# How to identify the addition/deletion across years in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hi I would like to identify which row is an addition/deletion compared to data in the previous year. Here is the data frame.

```
a <- data.frame(Ticker=c("AA","AA","BBX","AA","AAAAX","BBX"), Year=c(2009,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011))
```

I want to create a dummy variable I=1 if the Ticker has not been shown in the previous year. I want to create another dummy variable A=1 if Ticker has not been shown in any of the previous years. In this sample, there are only two years. But in the real data, there are around 10 years in total. The expected output is as follows,

```
b <- data.frame(Ticker=c("AA","AA","BBX","AA","AAAAX","BBX"), Year=c(2009,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011),I=c(0,0,1,0,1,0),A=c(0,0,1,0,1,0))
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean dummy variable? In a list? A dataframe? It would help to show full expected output.

Comment: I just added the expected output in the question. Thank you dcsuka!

Comment: How can some of them be both I and A? Or are the 1s and 0s arbitrary in your example?

Comment: Hi dcsuka, they are not arbitrary. "I" is to identify if the ticker appears in the previous year, for example, for the year 2010, we only compare it with 2009. "A" is to identify if the ticker appears in any of the previous years, for the year 2011, we compare it with all the tickers that are in 2009 and 2010.

Comment: Doesn't `ticker is new` mean the same thing as hasn't been shown in any of the previous years? Or should we ignore the ticker is new part. And shouldn't the first row have 1 and 1 as it is new?

Answer (score 2):

*data.table* version based on self-joins, just for fun.

The code sets both the `A` and `I` flags to `1`, then changes the rows to `0` when the previous year, or any prior year matches on `Ticker`:

I am joining the `a` dataset, back on itself via the data.table syntax `a[a]` (`table[jointable]`), joining `on=` the `Ticker` value, and also comparing the `Year`s within each matching `Ticker` group.
When there is a match, the `I` or `A` value is over-written `:=` with a `0`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)

a[, c("A","I","Yearp1") := .(1, 1, Year - 1)]
a[a, on=.(Ticker, Yearp1 = Year), I := 0]
a[a, on=.(Ticker, Year > Year), A := 0]
a[, Yearp1 := NULL]
a

#   Ticker Year A I
#1:     AA 2009 1 1
#2:     AA 2010 0 0
#3:    BBX 2010 1 1
#4:     AA 2011 0 0
#5:  AAAAX 2011 1 1
#6:    BBX 2011 0 0
```

Comment: Hi thelatemail, thank you! This is a very interesting solution! I have a follow-up question. I would like to use this method by GroupID. To be more specific, the dataset "a" is only the data for GroupID=1. My large dataset actually has GroupID from 1 to 1000. I am wondering how I can do this by GroupID?

Comment: @Jane - adding `GroupID` like `on=.(GroupID, Ticker, ...` should be enough I think.

Answer (score 1):

This solution makes two extra columns, one with only the previous year's tickers and one with all the previous tickers, and mutates based on inclusion in these groups.

```r
a %>%
  mutate(prevs = map(Year, function(x) filter(., x - 1 == Year)$Ticker),
         I = map2_dbl(Ticker, prevs, function(x, y) if_else(x %in% y, 0, 1)),
         all_prevs = map(Year, function(x) filter(., x > Year)$Ticker),
         A = map2_dbl(Ticker, all_prevs, function(x, y) if_else(x %in% y, 0, 1))) %>%
  select(Ticker, Year, I, A)

#   Ticker Year I A
# 1     AA 2009 1 1
# 2     AA 2010 0 0
# 3    BBX 2010 1 1
# 4     AA 2011 0 0
# 5  AAAAX 2011 1 1
# 6    BBX 2011 0 0
```

The first row is off, but it makes more sense this way as it technically has not been included in any previous years.

Comment: Hi dcsuka, thank you for your answer! This works great for the sample. However, this method is slow on big datasets. I'm wondering what would be a way to do it faster?

Comment: @Jane - try the *data.table* version I posted and see how it goes. Doing this as a join operation or in SQL should be a lot faster than essentially looping over values. Database operations are made for this sort of task.

Comment: Hi thelatemail, very cool, thank you! May I ask what is the function of "on=." here? Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @Jane - made some edits to my answer for more info.